# How are some Misadventures of P.B. Winterbottom players posting those leaderboard times?

Tags: misadventures-of-p.b.-winterbottom

*The Misadventures of P.B. Winterbottom* is absolutely brilliant (if maybe a little short). Anyway, now that I've finished it, I'm in the process of going through the bonus shorts (levels), and am somewhat curious as to how some people could have possibly posted the Steam leaderboard times that they have. Some levels have been beaten in as little as 5 seconds, when the target time to beat is 30 seconds. I suspect a degree of hacking is going on, but these times are posted through Steam. Any thoughts as to what might be going on?

A good example (for other P.B. Winterbottomers out there) is the bonus level called Cream of the Clock. (It is possible that the people who have posted these times are just THAT good, but I'm still skeptical...)

Comment: I felt the same every time I play a game with leaderboards. Is impressive how brilliant are some gamers and how bad am I :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually know the guy who set the Cream of the Clock record during the weekly competition they were having for that game, he has a video of it [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2fHRd-IYirs) (4.66s). Some games have glitches that let you get times you shouldn't be able to get on the leaderboards, but most of the time it's just people pulling off really impressive runs

Answer (score 2):

OK. I take back the remark about hacking. Much respect to the guy who made the following video:

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how Steam receives the highscore, it is possible that they don't actually check if the game has been modded, so no alarm bells will ring if I crafted a packet that claimed I finished the level in 2 seconds.

If the server is just a box that accepts messages and you figure out what the messages mean, you could write a message that claims whatever you so please as long as the server understands it.

For an example, check out html/sql-injection attacks on wikipedia.  (I'm not encouraging it, but it demonstrates the concept)